Request for clarification of a hint regarding the Portmanteau theorem
Let ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ be a sequence of real scalar random variables, and let ${X}$ be another scalar random variable. Then the following are equivalent:
(i) ${X_n}$ converges in distribution to ${X}$, which for the given context means that
$\displaystyle {\bf E}G(X_n) \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} {\bf E} G(X)$
for all continuous compactly supported functions ${G: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$. Or equivalently that $\displaystyle {\bf P}(X_n \leq t) \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} {\bf P}(X \leq t)$ for all continuity point $t$ of the distribution function $F_X$.
(ii) One has ${\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\bf P}( X_n \in K ) \leq {\bf P}(X \in K)}$ for all closed sets ${K \subset {\bf R}}$.
Note: Invoke Urysohn’s lemma. To deduce (ii) from (i), you may wish to start with the case of compact ${K}$. After that, show that for large $R$, the probability ${\bf P}(|X| \leq R)$ is close to 1, then show that the probability ${\bf P}(|X_n| \leq 2R)$ is close to 1 for large $n$, thus the probability ${\bf P}(|X_n| > 2R)$ is small.
Question: As suggested, to get (ii) from (i), one first establishes the case for compact $K$. As ${\bf P}(|X| \leq R)$ can get close to $1$ for large $R$, and for the same fixed $R$ the distance $|{\bf P}(|X_n| \leq R) - {\bf P}(|X| \leq R)|$ can get arbitrarily small for large $n$, we see that ${\bf P}(|X_n| \leq R)$ can get close to $1$ as well. The proof then follows by intersecting any closed $K$ with $[-R, R]$ for large $R$. The question is, what necessitates the factor $2$ in the term ${\bf P}(|X_n| \leq 2R)$ in the hint?

It's the statement on compacts which you showed plus tightness, both of which follow from $(i)$.

You already explained the statement on compacts.
As for tightness, fix some positive integer $N$, and let $f_N$ be the function equal to $0$ on $[-N,N]$ equal to $1$ on $|x|\ge N+1$ and linearly interpolated in the remaining two intervals.

Then $(i)$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[f_N (X_n)] = E[ f_N (X)]$.
But $P(|X_n|\ge N+1) \le E[ f_N (X_n)]$, and $E[ f_N (X)] \le P(|X|\ge N)$. Therefore
$$(*)\quad \limsup P(|X_n| \ge N+1) \le E[f_N (X)] \le P(|X|\ge N).$$
This gives the tightness. Now let's finish. Let $F$ be any closed set. Then
$$ P(X_n \in F) \le  P(X_n \in F \cap [-N-1,N+1])+ P(|X_n|\ge N+1).$$
Using the fact that $F\cap [-N-1,N+1]$ is compact and the statement on compacts, we have
$$ \limsup P(X_n \in F) \overset{\scriptsize{\mbox{compacts}},(*)}{\le} P(X \in F \cap [-N-1,N+1]) + P(|X|\ge N).$$
The righthand side is bounded above by $P(X \in F) + P(|X|\ge N)$. As $N$ is arbitrary, and $\lim_{N\to\infty} P(|X|\ge N)=0$, the proof is now established.

Sure, this is a working explicit argument. The hint invokes Urysohn's lemma to implicitly find the continuous middle function $f$ even when the underlying space is a general topological space $X$ on which the act of linear interpolation is not well defined.

My issue concerns only the last part of the hint that generalize to the closed case. Directly from the compact case, for $I_N = [-N, N]$:
\begin{align*}
\lim \sup_n {\bf P}(X_n \in K) &\leq \lim \sup_n {\bf P}(X_n \in K \cap
I_N) + \lim \sup_n {\bf P}(|X_n| > N)
\
&\leq {\bf P}(X \in K \cap I_N) +  \lim \sup_n {\bf P}(|X_n| > N)
\end{align*}
Taking $N \to \infty$ and using the property of the distribution function of both $X$ and $X_n$ yields the result.  Thus I'm not sure about the necessity of the factor $2$ in the term ${\bf P}(|X_n|) > 2N)$.

As it turns out, two applications of Urysohn's lemma establishes the claim, as usual, verifications are welcomed.
First assume (i), and $K \subset {\bf R}$ compact. For integers $i = 1, 2, \dots$, define open sets
$U_i := \{x \in {\bf R}: d(x, K) < 1/i\}$, where $d$ is the distance function.
Then $K \subset U_i$ for all $i$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i = K$. In particular
$\lim_{i \to \infty} {\bf P}(X \in U_i) = {\bf P}(X \in K)$ by continuity from above. By Urysohn's lemma, for each $i$ we can find a continuous function $f_i: {\bf R} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ which equals $1$ on $K$ and $0$ on $\overline{U_i}$. By monotonicity and (i) we have
$\displaystyle \lim\sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(X_n \in K) \leq \lim\sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf E}f_i(X_n) = {\bf E}f_i(X) \leq {\bf E}1_{X \in U_i} = {\bf P}(X \in U_i)$
Taking $i \to \infty$ on both sides gives (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) for compact $K$.
To generalize to a closed $K$, fixed $\varepsilon > 0$. As $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} F_X(t) = 1/0$, we can find some large $R$ depending on $\varepsilon$ such that ${\bf P}(|X| \leq R) \geq 1 - \varepsilon$. By Urysohn's lemma again, we find a continuous function $f$ supported on $B(0, 2R)$ which equals $1$ on $B(0, R)$. Apply $f$ to both $X$ and $X_n$ gives $1_{[-R, R]}(X_n) \leq f(X_n) \leq 1_{(-2R, 2R)}(X_n)$, and similarly $1_{[-R, R]}(X) \leq f(X) \leq 1_{(-2R, 2R)}(X)$. Thus
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(|X_n| \leq R) \leq {\bf E}f(X_n) \leq {\bf P}(X_n \leq 2R)$,
and likewise
${\bf P}(|X| \leq R) \leq {\bf E}f(X) \leq {\bf P}(X \leq 2R)$.
By (i) we have ${\bf E}f(X_n) \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} {\bf E}f(X)$, from the inequalities above one gets
$\displaystyle |{\bf P}(|X_n| \leq 2R) - {\bf P}(|X| \leq R)| \leq |{\bf E}f(X_n) - {\bf E}f(X)| \leq \varepsilon$
for large $n$. In particular we see that ${\bf P}(|X_n| \leq 2R) \geq 1 - 2\varepsilon$, so
${\bf P}(|X_n| > 2R) \leq 2\varepsilon$.
Now, for any closed $K \subset {\bf R}$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(X_n \in K) &=  \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(X_n \in K \cap [-2R, 2R]) + \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(X_n \in K \cap \overline{[-2R, 2R]})
    \\
    &\leq \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(X \in K \cap [-2R, 2R]) + \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(|X_n| > 2R)
    \\
    &\leq {\bf P}(X \in K) + \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\bf P}(|X_n| > 2R).
\end{align*}
Let $\varepsilon \to 0$ along a countable set (so that $R$ also tends to infinity along a countable set), we obtain the claim for closed $K$.
